# Random HTML Link Generator

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am wishing to produce a html file that when accessed draws from a batch of URLs choosing a random one and sending the user directly to this random link.

This function would occur when a user clicks a link eg "www.thepegeek.com/random" which would wind up drawing from the list of possible URLs

Any suggestions as to how this might be possible with HTML and so that the batch of URLS can be updated as needed.I am looking to host this using my dropbox account.

Comment: Will not be possible with plain HTML. You will have to use JavaScript and modify `document.location.href`, or some server-side language that redirect the user to a random URL.

Comment: You could always e-mail StumbleUpon and ask for all of their codez

Answer (score 2):

This will not be possible with plain HTML.

You will either have to use JavaScript, keep the URLs in an array or object, and when the user click on the link, you catch the event, pick a random URL from the array and modify `document.location.href` to send the user there. *Not sure how much JavaScript dropbox will allow you to run though, so you will have try that out*

The other option would be to use a server-side language of your choice and redirect the user to a random URL. *That would however not work if you plan to host it on dropbox.*